# I use python subprocess to enter the password in Ubuntu 18, but in the terminal it opens the input

Tags: python

This script works for mac python 3.8, ubuntu 20, but does not work for ubuntu 18 with python 3.6

```
        command = 'pg_dump -U {user} -h localhost {db_name} > {dir}{filename}.dump'.format(
            user=db_user, db_name=db_name, dir=self._dump_dir, filename=backup_file_name)
        p = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
        p.communicate(input='{}\n'.format(db_password).encode())
```

What is the problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x63L0.png)

Comment: What is the exception being raised?...

Comment: @MarkR. no exceptions are thrown, no input occurs. The input line opens in the terminal "Password: "

Comment: how are you running this script on both platforms? what is the issue you are encountering?

Comment: @ExtraFishness no exceptions are thrown. The input line "Password:" opens in the terminal.

Comment: Why not provide the password via an environment variable (`PGPASSFILE` or `PGPASSWORD`, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) instead of trying to provide it interactively?

Comment: @larsks good idea, thanks